# Edit content at URL in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I'm a complete COMPLETE noob at Drupal.

I've been handed a large very customized Drupal 7 site after our admin quit. I have tons of WP experience, but zilch in Drupal.

I've been asked to edit a page that exists at:

http://my.drupalsite.com/[page]

The page functions only to redirect to:

http://my.othersite.com/

But, I need to change part of the way it redirects. Normally (as in, the one other time I did it) to edit a Drupal page, I just go to the page logged in as an admin and click "edit". Since this is a redirect page, I can't really do this. The /admin/content section has 83 pages of 25 items each with no way for me to search on *anything* and no way to tell from what the guy called the page as to what page actually does this redirect. I'll be a monkey's uncle if I'm going to click on every darn one of them and then click the "URL path settings" tab at the bottom to see which one of these suckers is the page I'm after.

Surely this is simple for even a typical Drupal novice... like I said though, complete noob.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: yes, I do have access to my db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few modules that can handle redirection or even simple editing of a path.

You can look at pathauto
https://drupal.org/project/pathauto

On that page you should find other recommendations such as the Global Redirect & Redirect modules. I'm pretty sure some of these modules will simplify your task. You should be able to take an existing path and redirect it to wherever you wish, without having to dig in each URL alias on the node edit page.

It's always difficult to give specific advice without knowing more, but , for instance,  Pathauto can help you change the path of a specific content type to a specific pattern. That can come very handy if you need to change a bunch of pages with a similar structure.